# bootstrap modal as jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Using the example of bootstraps modal

```
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

I was wondering if there is a way to make this, some sort of dynamic via `jQuery`.

My goal is to have something like a variable called `$theModal` which will be initialized and has properties for getting/setting the title, the content, the javascipt-functions to be called when Save/Cancel/Close is clicked etc.

Should all be generated via `jQuery` or should I have the markup in the code and use ids/custom data-attributes to catch the modal?

Maybe some class-structure?

```
var $theModal = new MyModal();
```

Next question would be, how to create a clone in case a modal is already open?

I would make/guess

```
var $theClone = $theModal.clone().init();

$theClone.title = "Title of the second modal";
$theClone.content = $.ajax(url);
$theClone.saveAction = saveTheContentOfTheContent;
$theClone.show();
```

Is this possible or am I totally wrong with my assumptions?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea isnt too bad, but...

You could have one modal in your html code. 
Then in the space Where your title would be you could use the $scope type.

Then in your js file you could specify the strings you want in arrays and just change to the one you want in the parameter of an ng-click function.

## index.html

```
<p>This is the modal view.</p>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">{{msgArray.title}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>{{msgArray.body}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">{{msgArray.btn}}</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

## script.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.msgArray1 = {
        title : "Modal 1",
        body: "This is the co to say anything you want here.",
        btn : "Close",
    };
     $scope.msgArray2 = {
        title : "Modal 2",
        body: "This is the co to say anything you want here.",
        btn : "Close",
    };

        $scope.msgTemp = {
        title : "",
        body: "",
        btn : "",
    };

    $scope.openModal = function(modal){

      if(modal == "modal1"){
        $scope.msgTemp = $scope.msgArray1;
      }
              if(modal == "modal2"){
        $scope.msgTemp = $scope.msgArray2;
      }

      $("#myModal").modal('show');

    }

});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/nV3iq1U1ymcsBAXT6g2y?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is very good and it is already implemented by somene. Check out [this link](https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/)

This link demonstrate you every possible case scenario in which your idea can be used. It also has some tremendous features which we don't have even thought of.